# Magento2: How to add 3rd party payment getaway?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I need to integrate **PayTrace** 3rd party payment gateway in Magento 2.

Can you explain how to add it?

https://www.paytrace.net/developer

My Magento v2.0.17

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sample **[Magento_SamplePaymentGateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway)** module files as basis for your custom module structure and files.

> Your custom payment integration module must have at least the
>   following dependencies:

- `Magento_Sales` module: to be able to get order details
- `Magento_Payment` module: to use the Magento payment provider gateway
  infrastructure
- `Magento_Checkout` module: to be able to add the new payment method to
  checkout .

> If you do not plan to use it on the storefront checkout, this
>   dependency is not required.

Specify these dependencies in your `composer.json` and `module.xml` files.

> `composer.json`

`%Vendor_Module%/composer.json` file, specify the dependencies like in the following example:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "magento/module-payment": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-sales": "100.1.*",
        ...
    },
    ...

}
```

> **module.xml**

Add the same dependencies in `%Vendor_Module%/etc/module.xml` like in the following example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            ...
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            ...
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

---

After this follow Magento DevDocs

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/payment-option-config.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/facade-configuration.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/formblocktype.html

---

For more reference

- https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-payment-gateways.html
- https://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/

Comment: Can we add any 3rd party payment getaway?  https://www.paytrace.net/developer

Comment: Yes ofcause http://help.paytrace.com/api/

Comment: paytrace can be implement in magento

Comment: Just follow the process

Comment: Ok, I will follow the step and create it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: First read all the devdocs related to payment

Comment: Which i mentioned in answer

Comment: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/

Comment: Ok, I will read the DevDocs related to payment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84283/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: @MasudShaikh Have you created paytrace payment module?

Comment: @Kul No, I have not created PayTrace module.

Answer (score 1):

We have created new extension for paytrace, you can review it here

https://www.elsner.com/magento-extension/paytrace-payment-gateway-magento-2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to create a new custom payment method in Magento 2 with a simple example:

1. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/registration.php** to register your payment gateway extension.
   [image: Magecomp/Stripe/registration.php]
2. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/composer.json**
   [image: Magecomp/Stripe/composer.json]
3. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/etc/module.xml** to define your module name.
   [image: Magecomp/Stripe/etc/module.xml]
4. Create **Magecomp/Strpe/etc/config.xml** to define your stripe payment method.
5. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/etc/adminhtml/system.xml** to display payment method in admin payment method section.
6. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/etc/frontend/di.xml** for dependency Injection configuration.
7. Create model file to define payment method
   **Magecomp/Stripe/Model/Payment.php**
8. Create model file to define Allowed CC type
   **Magecomp/Stripe/Model/Source/Cctype.php**
   [image: Magecomp/Stripe/Model/Source/Cctype.php]
9. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/ stripepayments.js** to register our template or renderer file.
   [image: Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/ stripepayments.js]
10. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/ stripemethod.js**
    [image: Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/ stripemethod.js]
11. Create
    **Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/web/template/payment/stripe.html** template file.
12. Create **Magecomp/Stripe/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml** to define payment method at checkout page.
13. Run below commands to install above extension:
    [image: Command]

If you follow these steps in a perfect manner, you can see your custom payment method (here Stripe payment method) at the checkout page. I hope these steps for [payment gateway magento 2](https://www.elsner.com/magento-extension/paytrace-payment-gateway-magento-2-paytrace) were helpful to serve your purpose. Comments and queries are always welcomed feel free to reach me out.